# How to export a date into excel that will format based on operating system settings?

Tags: java, excel, internationalization, date-formatting

I'm using Java and the apache poi library. I can set up dates to export into different formats just fine using workbook.getCreationHelper().createDataFormat().getFormat("d/m/yyy") and such.

What I'm trying to do, however, is allow the date to be formatted based on operating system settings. Essentially, I want to select one of the two options shown below, but programmatically.

(Sorry - screenshot not provided because I don't have enough reputation points. I found an example here. See the screenshot that shows the date formats in excel marked with an *: http://excelsemipro.com/2011/06/regional-date-formats-in-excel/ )

If this has been answered elsewhere, I'd love a link. I've not had success in searching for it myself.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As long as you pass the date as a value and not text it will format based on the Excel default (which is related to but not always the same as the system default).

Comment: Thank you @jbarker2160. I am indeed passing the date as a value, not a String. When I don't set any CellStyle, Excel displays the value as a double. Not quite what I'm going for.

I don't believe that's my Excel or System default... though I'm not sure how to verify that.

Comment: Seems as if numFmtId="14" in OpenXML is a general date format. At least in German Excel 2007 it is not explicit defined in a numFmt element but nevertheless it is applied as NumberFormat . So should in POI `cellStyle.setDataFormat((short)14)` generate a date format which is general usable in all locales? At least for me in German Excel 2007 and libreoffice in English(USA) this is the case. German Excel gets this as TT.MM.JJJJ and English libreoffice gets it as M/D/YYYY.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to get back on and post my result. It turned out that setting it as a date did indeed do the trick. By giving the cell style a date format, it didn't display it as a double, but then Excel didn't honor the date format if a language other than English was selected. It just switched it to whatever its default was for that language. That was actually just what I wanted. :)